# FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/foo.png in Play Store crash logs only

Tags: android

We've seen about 40 of these crashes in the past two days of our app release for 4.0.  After reviewing crash logs, we've discovered it's existence since version 3.3 of our app.  We have been unable to reproduce this in house.

Further research has indicated this problem is prevalent in other applications, but I was unable to find a resolution or an indication that Google is aware of the issue.

The crash itself happens on the setContentView(R.layout.foo) method call in onCreate()

Notes:

- We limit our API to version 4 and target 15.
- We've seen this on at least 2.2 - 4.0.3 on mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi phones and tablets.
- User comments specify that the app crashes immediately (expected) and that the Evernote icon in the application launcher turns to the default app icon (cannot read any drawables).
- The crash is not limited to one specific drawable, we have seen many different ones in the logs, however they all "seem" to be image drawables, not colors, layouts, xml files, etc...
- This is not limited to 9patches, it has happened on both regular .png and .9.png

Our drawable folders look like the picture attached [image: Drawables]

- We store only xml in our drawable folder

Stack trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ics_tab_title_unselected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02016f
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
at com.evernote.ics.ActionBarTabbedTitle.a(ActionBarTabbedTitle.java:103)
at com.evernote.ics.j.a(ActivityActionBar.java:150)
at com.evernote.ics.a.c(ActionBar.java:731)
at com.evernote.ics.a.p(ActionBar.java:440)
at com.evernote.ics.a.g(ActionBar.java:423)
at com.evernote.ics.j.m(ActivityActionBar.java:68)
at com.evernote.ics.phone.SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.s(SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.java:990)
at com.evernote.ics.phone.SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.a(SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.java:662)
at com.evernote.ics.phone.SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.b(SwipeableTabbedActivityAbstract.java:617)
at com.evernote.ics.phone.PhoneMainActivity.b(PhoneMainActivity.java:113)
at com.evernote.ui.EvernoteFragment.a(EvernoteFragment.java:136)
at com.evernote.ui.EvernoteFragment.a(EvernoteFragment.java:132)
at com.evernote.ui.EvernoteFragment.d(EvernoteFragment.java:128)
at com.evernote.ics.phone.b.onItemClick(HomeFragment.java:1324)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/tab_unselected_focus.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0201e6
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/tab_unselected_focus.9.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
... 33 more
```

Any recommendations would greatly be appreciated.

App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote

Thanks,

Ty

Comment: "that the Evernote icon turns to the default app icon (cannot read any drawables)" -- could you elaborate a bit more on this? Do you mean that the launcher icon is the default app icon? Does this seem to occur every time you also get one of these stack traces, or is that just another independent symptom?

Comment: The user comments indicated that the launcher icon for the app itself turned into the default icon (green robot).

Comment: The stack trace happens when the user launches the app and setContentView is called on whichever activity is the entry point.  We have yet to be in contact with a user experiencing it directly, so we are trying to derive from our analytics, market crashes, and user comments on crash.

Comment: have you tried to replace the problematic image with something else , maybe even remove whatever view that is showing it? does it still occur on this cases too?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but as mentioned above, this isn't limited to one specific resource or one specific layout file.  It seems to be the first drawable in each layout file that is the first used inside the first activity the user accesses (multiple entry points).

Comment: Off the cuff, it feels like a failed install, but that's just a guess.

Comment: That's one option we were exploring.  Corrupted APK in the market cache.

Comment: Did you find the cause or the fix? If I extract my apk (changed the extension to zip), I can see the "drawable-xhdpi-v4" folder and the png which was not found by device. I don't understand why the device can't

Comment: @tsmith Do you solve this issue? I saw in Google Report this crash still confused people...

Answer (score 0):

similar error solved by adding the following in the "proguard" file.

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```